# Rooting & AOSP Android - Howto

Tags: lg-optimus-one, vanilla-android, vanilla-ui

I'm about to buy a new Android phone, and I'm looking at the [LG Optimus One P500](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_optimus_one_p500-3516.php). IMHO it's a little better than comparable models from other brands (eg. Samsung Galaxy Fit), but there's only one problem that I have with it: I want a "pure-Google experience" as in AOSP Android as seen in the Nexus S et al. So, before going ahead and buying it, I'd like to ask whether it's possible to root the phone and somehow achieve what I want (and remove the custom LG modifications, esp. the dock).

Also I've heard that the variant used on the Optimus V isn't modified as much - can that be used with the Optimus One?

Comment: You can ask the offtopic part in [our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android) or a forum or something, but leave it out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

For rooting, see [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone)

You should be able to use another launcher regardless, but you can get a close-to-AOSP experience with CyanogenMOD.  I don't believe that phone is officially supported by CM but someone's porting it: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=946354

The XDA Android Development forum for the Optimus One was only recently broken off from the Optimus V forum, so the ROMs probably can be used interchangeably with minor tweaks.  I suggest asking on XDA though.